# How to I calculate absolute position of individual frames inside a frameset (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, frame, frameset

I have to support a website that still supports framesets. My use case is to find the absolute position of a frame in the frameset. I can get its width and height, but I also need its left and top coordinate. I need this to find an element's position inside the frame with respect to the main document.

Sample code can be taken from https://www.javatpoint.com/oprweb/test.jsp?filename=htmlframetag2

I just need a way to determine where the frame's computed position is.

Comment: perhaps the frames `.getBoundingClientRect`?

Comment: getBoundingClientRect is not available on the frame or it's window object. It's only available on the body tag and that returns the rect only relative to itself, which means the left and top is always zero.In "iframes" it works, getBoundingClientRect is supported, but can't get it to work for frame tags.

Comment: you must be doing it wrong - works fine in my testing of your code

Comment: Could you please post a short snippet?
I get this -
window.frames[0].getBoundingClientRect();

VM245:1 Uncaught TypeError: window.frames[0].getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:18

Comment: could be your browser (what browser?) or could be that at the time `window.frames[0]` is `undefined` - i.e. you're attempting to perform a function in an object that doesn't yet exist - so, it's not about what code you are using, it's about when you are using it

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome. I have written this on window.onload

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't working probably because I was only running the script for the main window frames. Works with recursion now.